# How to search the help docs from a command prompt?

Tags: invocation, help-system

I find my self often, especially after this site was created, opening Vim just to type `:h ...` or `:helpgrep ...`.

What I would like to do is to run Vim and immediately open the help topic that I want. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-c` argument to execute a command after Vim starts up:

```
vim -c ':help TOPIC' -c :only
```

You may want to define a shell function:

```
vimhelp () {
  vim -c ":help $1" -c :only
}
```

Comment: (t)csh alias: `alias vimhelp 'vim -c ':help $1' -c :only'`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Did you find a time machine to go back to the late 1980s/early 1990s, the time when tcsh was worth using? Can you share?

Comment: @Gilles some people still post questions about it on AU/U&L - corporate environments, I suppose. :(

Comment: You can also put the `:only` option in the same command: `vim -c ':help TOPIC | only'`