# Invoke vi help from bash without starting Vim

Tags: help-system, bash

How do I invoke the vi `help` while I am in bash without starting a vi session?

Comment: You can't; not in any useful way. Why do you want to do this? What's the problem you're tryng to solve?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think it would save me a few seconds when I don't start a session to seek help for a particular keybind for example.

Comment: You can use `vim +':help foo'`; although I doubt that's really faster since you lack tab-completion. And it *will* start Vim, obviously.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I wrote a bash script along the lines of [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2418/10566) of the duplicated question. Thanks a ton :).